# host -unknown by using docker-compose and jitsi-meet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jitsi

My goal is to run jitsi-meet and another docker container on my CentOS. For this purpose, i created a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

    jitsi-meet:
        image: robertoandrade/jitsi-meet
        container_name: jitsi-meet
        hostname: 192.168.5.169
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "443:443
```

When i run it with docker-compose up i get the following error message:

```
JVB 2017-10-23 12:20:33.925 INFO: [10] org.jitsi.videobridge.octo.OctoRelay.start().106 Octo relay not configured.
JVB 2017-10-23 12:20:33.964 SEVERE: [27] org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain.call().278 host-unknown, host:localhost, port:5347
org.xmpp.component.ComponentException: host-unknown
         at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponent.connect(ExternalComponent.java:219)
         at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:221)
         at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:201)
         at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:270)
         at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:255)
         at org.jitsi.retry.RetryStrategy$TaskRunner.run(RetryStrategy.java:193)
         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 JVB 2017-10-23 12:20:34.042 INFO: [14] org.ice4j.ice.harvest.MappingCandidateHarvesters.initialize() Initialized mapping harvesters (delay=652ms).  stunDiscoveryFailed=false
```

When I run the image with *docker run -it --name jitsi-meet -p 443:443 robertoandrade/jitsi-meet* I get an input prompt for the hostname and it started flawlessly.

Attempt with "stdin_open: true" and "tty: true" as mentioned by Matt.

Note: I operate per PuTTY ssh.

Result:

```
unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
c.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
ing jitsi-videobridge
-----------------------------

The jisti-videobridge package needs the DNS hostname of your instance.
```

How can I make it work with docker-compose?

I would prefer a solution without the manual input.

Comment: `hostname: 192.168.5.169`, this seems like the main difference between compose and direct run. Can yuo remove this line and retry?

Comment: @yamenk I got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that docker image requires user input to start, which is why `-i` and `-t` are used in the `docker run` command.

`-i` keeps standard input open.
`-t` assigns a pseudo tty to the process so it thinks there is a console

[The `stdin_open` and `tty` options can be set in a compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) too.

```
version: '2'

services:

    jitsi-meet:
        image: robertoandrade/jitsi-meet
        container_name: jitsi-meet
        restart: always
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "443:443
```

Normally services don't require input so they can be run in the background. 
Most container images would set up an environment variable or config file to set configuration options like hostnames.

Comment: I tried it but got new error messages and updated my question. I also don't like the user input and tried to get rid of by setting the hostname in the docker-compose. With no effect :(

Comment: You probably need to rewrite their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/robertoandrade/docker-jitsi-meet/blob/master/Dockerfile) then, to be honest I'd do that anyway. Remove the `dpkg-reconfigure` from run.sh.  Manage the 4 services in run.sh with [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay). Create an entrypoint script that sets up the config files like the [commented lines in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/robertoandrade/docker-jitsi-meet/blob/master/Dockerfile#L14-L18) once did, but via run time environment variables.

Comment: s6 [provides it's own `entrypoint` like initialisation system](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay#executing-initialization-andor-finalization-tasks).

Comment: I tried same things and one was the install instruction from jitsi-meet (https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md). I got no error message but the site was not reachable. Oddly it didn't ask for a hostname input like the old version from robertoandrade.